# Send message to Android phone using bluetooth

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, serial-port, bluetooth, bluez

I have a Raspberry Pi which you can assume to be just a Linux machine. It runs BlueZ and is successfully paired with my Android phone.

What I want to do is, my Python program should be able to send a message to my Android phone through Bluetooth. I think this may require a Bluetooth serial connection, but I browsed my Android phone's channels, didn't know which service should I bind rfcomm to.

I did quite a lot of research on Google about this. I think most of the articles talk about how to control Raspberry Pi with an Android phone.

Some articles say I can add an SP service to Raspberry Pi and use a Bluetooth terminal on my phone to connect to it. First I didn't succeed with that. The connection is established and then lost immediately. Second I don't know how to implement my program if I create it that way. I am wondering if there's a better solution.

---

I hope it can be the Android phone who creates an SP service and let the Raspberry Pi to bind it as an rfcomm device, like what we usually do with Bluetooth GPS modules.